# asp.net mvc vs java spring on linux

Tags: java, asp.net, spring, mono

I am doing a POC for a project that required hosting on linux server, and using iphone, ipad etc to interact with the server.

I have strong background in asp.net mvc, however have little knowledge in java and no experience in java spring.

for the requirement, i have to use HTML5 with toggling to multiple views at the controller to support multiple platform, or i could be using phoneGap to render the view.

If I opt to use asp.net MVC , i have to use Mono to develop (which the latest release of 2.10 supports asp.net MVC 3) , and apache to host the application.

If i opt to use java spring, all the support for the application seems native without much "hacking".

The question is that is it worth to use java , which will have some learning curve for me and my team, with benefits (performance or the support) or i should go with the asp.net mvc with Mono in which we need to learn only the Mono in order to develop it for linux server?

Comment: using asp.net on linux is a bit like asking for a bacon sandwich without the bacon.

Answer (score 0):

> is that is it worth to use java , which will have some learning curve for me and my team, with benefits (**performance** or the **support**) or i should go with the asp.net mvc with Mono in which we need to learn only the Mono

For G-WAN, we have recently added support for Java (JVM) and C# (Mono).

What can be said at this stage (the release supporting Mono will be published by the end of the month) is that both **perform** 'equally' from G-WAN (Mono consumes a bit less RAM).

This is *not the case* when Java or Mono is used from other app. servers (you will have to make your tests on a per-case basis).

I got relevant and responsive **support** from Mono when I asked a question during a week-end (!) but Java is offering a larger number of support options (many companies provide Java solutions and support plans).

That's merely my personal experience.